# Max value data entry Python tkinter without validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Is there a possibility to set a max value for a data entry?
*For example:*
Max value = 350, someone enters 400, the value automatically chances to 350.

I thought something like

```
if int(entry1.get()) > 350:
    int(entry1) = 350
```

But I can’t get this to work because of an int error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should put this inside of a function and then use binding or trace it with `IntVar()` or by using `after()`

Comment: This also can be done without validation, indeed a much easier way, voting to reopen the Q

Comment: @CoolCloud - The linked duplicate (along with many others) asks the same question at hand. If you have a new answer for that question that hasn't been posted yet, _answer that question_ rather than reopening a duplicate and fragmenting the information.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 This Q has been edited and no more asks for validation. I voted to reopen the Q because here there is no need for such validations at all, and cant just expect people to understand that.

Comment: If I understand validation correctly it only indicates whether it is true or flase. And i need to change the value when it above max to the max value? I dont get why its a duplicate Q.

Comment: If you dont mind, delete this Q and ask a new Q, ill answer there